# How to add column in table having default datetime value of timestamp

Tags: mariadb, alter-table, sqldatetime

I want to add a column in my table `police_publiclocation` where column must have 5hr and 30min greater value than current `TIMESTAMP` value.

I am doing the following but it is not working..
Please provide me some solution.. Thanks in advance..

```
ALTER TABLE `police_publiclocation` ADD `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+CONVERT(Datetime, '2011-09-28 05:30:00',120) AFTER `active`;
```

**ERROR:**
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '+CONVERT(Datetime, '2011-09-28 05:30:00') AFTER `active`' at line 1

**USING FOLLOWING**

MYSQL

phpMyAdmin
Version information: 4.6.6 , latest stable version: 4.7.2

Database server

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.20-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.0.8

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please remove in irrelevant tags as the answer depends on the DBMS.

Comment: According to Maria DB documentation:
DEFAULT with expressions was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.1,
You wrote you are on version 10.1.20, so I guess default expressions will not work in your case.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/

Comment: In versions prior to MariaDB 10.2.1, one option is to use a [PREPARE Statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/prepare-statement/).

Answer (score 0):

With MariaDB 10.2, you can have arbitrary expressions in `DEFAULT`.

Otherwise, consider using a `TRIGGER` to set it.